# Why can't we have a three dimensional system for rotations?

Tags: complex-numbers, rotations, quaternions, number-systems

We can have $i^2=-1=j^2$. This allows rotations in the $(1,i)$-plane and $(1,j)$-plane. And I think Euler has a result that rotations about arbitrary axes can be described by successive rotations about the perpendicular $x$, $y$,  $z$ axes (correct me if I'm wrong). But this system maybe does not allow rotations in the $(i,j)$-plane because of both $i$ and $j$ squaring to −1 (We haven't defined $i\cdot j$ either). Is this why we don't have a three dimensional number system? If not, then what's the reason we need four dimensions?

Comment: You can look up the quaternions. The idea is that it may be a bit more complicated since applying a rotation $R_1$ then $R_2$ is not the same as applying $R_2$ then $R_1$, meaning that $ij \neq ji$.

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly. We have a two dimensional number system to represent rotations in the plane, namely the complex numbers. Multiplying by i rotates a complex number by 90 degrees. if you want to rotate in 3D, you can extend this concept to Quaternions. Quaternions do exactly what you want, they follow Eulers results about rotations. indeed you have to define then, what $ij, jk, ik$ and $ijk$ are, where $i^2=j^2=k^2 = -1$

Comment: @Luke The question is 'What issues does a 1,i,j number system has which are solved by adding an extra k-axis? Before discovering quaternions, Hamilton tried hard to make it work with only 1,i,j axes.

Comment: We can represent 3D rotations as 3 numbers (euler angles) but such a representation is non-linear and difficult to work with. An analogy is a two dimensional map of the earth, there is no way that we can map the surface of the earth without distorting either angles or areas. However once the 2D map is wrapped around a 3D sphere it becomes linear, in a similar way the 3D space of rotations becomes linear when it is mapped to a 4D hypersphere. Maybe have a look at https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/theory/index.htm

Comment: I think your intuition is essentially on the right track, but you may need to make it a bit more precise. I will try to make it more precise. Let us assume that there exists a $3$-dimensional real (associative) division algebra $F$, endowed with a conjugation map, sending $a \in F$ to $\bar{a}$, which is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, and satisfies $\overline{ab} = \bar{b} \bar{a}$.

Comment: Then $G = \{ a \in F; a\bar{a} = 1\}$ is a $2$-dimensional real Lie group. Define $\operatorname{Im}(F) = \{ a \in F; a + \bar{a} = 0 \}$. Let $S \subset \operatorname{Im}{F}$ be the subset of elements $a$ satisfying also $a \bar{a} = 1$. Define an action of $G$ on $S$ by $g.a = ga\bar{g}$.

Comment: My idea is to try to derive a contradiction by first showing that $G$ must be abelian (by looking at its Lie algebra and using the Jacobi identity), and also show that $\operatorname{Im}(F)$ can be identified with its Lie algebra, so that the adjoint action of $G$ on $S$ is trivial. Then use that to show that $F$ must be abelian.

Comment: Hence $F$ is a $3$-dimensional field extension of $\mathbb{R}$. But from field theory, we know that such a field extension does not exist. We have thus derived a contradiction. One may have to check some details in my argument, but I think it is essentially correct.

Comment: Although the tag 'number-theory' is definitely inappropriate for the question, it is clear what was intended, yet there does not seem to exist an appropriate tag with which to replace it! In particular, 'number-systems' is for something else entirely. There are many tags for particular systems of 'numbers', yet no tag for concepts of 'numbers' in general. When the question of such a concept arises, it tends to be dismissed with the suggestion that there simply *is* no such general concept. Perhaps there should be a tag 'number-concepts'? After all, there are many *books* all about 'numbers'.

Comment: @Malkoun I appreciate you giving an answer but sadly I don't 
understand most of the words you used. I guess I should have mentioned my math-level

Comment: @RyderRude, see for instance <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra> and <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)>. If you need further help, I may write more if I have time. Think of a finite-dimensional real division algebra as a reasonable way to make precise the notion of a finite-dimensional "number system" over $\mathbb{R}$.